# How to make a invalid json to val;id json in python

Tags: python

my json string:

```
"{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/5472540504.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'},
{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3901883467.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},
{'Link': 'http://www.nbagr.res.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"
```

expecting dictcionary:

```
[
  {'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/5472540504.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'},
  {'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3901883467.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},
  {'Link': 'http://www.nbagr.res.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}
]
```

how can i convert first invalid dictionary to valid like 2nd one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's not valid JSON, but you can pass the string to [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) if you surround it with brackets:

```
>>> s="""{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/5472540504.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'},
... {'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3901883467.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},
... {'Link': 'http://www.nbagr.res.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"""
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[" + s + "]")
[{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/5472540504.pdf', 'Title': 'Corrigendum'}, 
 {'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/3901883467.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '}, 
 {'Link': 'http://www.nbagr.res.in/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}]
```

Comment: why """ instead if "

Comment: can we do it with " ?

Comment: Since there are linebreaks in the string, you need `"""`, otherwise it's a syntax error. Or did I misunderstand your question and your string actually contains these quotes? In that case, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can exactly reproduce your problem.

Comment: how can i make single " string to """ ?? means suppose string is "hello" how to make it """hello"""

Comment: I would really recommend you fix the input instead. (Using the AST is quite clever, though.)

Comment: Absolutely. But after OP's comments, I'm not really sure what the actual problem is...

Comment: using ast it is giving errors:

    dict = ast.literal_eval("[" + s + "]")
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: So `s` is a list, not a string. Did you read my comment above. We can't tell what your problem is if you don't specify it precisely enough. A MCVE doesn't need to contain your database, but it would help if you could show `repr(s)`. Please edit your question instead of posting code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with a **malformed** JSON file here: JSON uses double quotes (") not single quotes ('). Your JSON string can't seem to decide whether it's linewise JSON (but with trailing commas) or just regular JSON (but without [] with line breaks instead). I would highly recommend you **fix the input**.

That said, this code should load the objects from your string:

```
import json
docs = [ json.loads(line.strip(",")) for line in json_string.replace("'", '"').split("\n") ]
```

Keep in mind this is tailored specifically for your input. It *will* break if your input contains escaped linebreaks, escaped quotation chars or some such thing.

And that's why it would be best you fixed the input to **proper** JSON. Then you could  just load the docs with

```
docs = json.loads(json_string)  # for '[{"Link":"http://foo.com","Title":"foo"}]'
```

or

```
docs = [ json.loads(line) for line in json_string.split("\n") ]  # for linewise JSON
```

Which is much more stable and maintainable.

Comment: how can i make single " string to """ ?? means suppose string is "hello" how to make it """hello""" –

Comment: otherwise it is breaking the line

Comment: @SoubhagyaPradhan Where did you get your input json string from?

Comment: from my  database

Comment: @SoubhagyaPradhan In a TEXT or VARCHAR column? How did they write to the database? Any chance you can fix that?